# Basic cross platform app using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

i'm newbie in Xamarin. am download all components and i don't know how to develop cross platform app for iOS, android and windows.
if u have any tutorial step to step app development. please help me.

Comment: All documentation is on the xamarin website. They have fantastic guides to help anyone at any level build a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/) it is the official guides, they are pretty much helpful for basic development, you will have to use [Xamarin.iOS](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/) and [Xamarin.Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) to develop some specific thing more related to the platform.